# Can any goverment permanently ban all the VPN servers around the world

Tags: network, vpn

I think the question is clear on the title. Is it technically possible?

Comment: Do you mean "can a government prevent all VPNs from being used in their own country?" or "can a government prevent all VPNs from being used anywhere in the world?". And when you say "ban" do you mean actually prevent the use of, or simply "outlaw"? I think you need to clarify your title ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes: they can create a whitelist of all allowed sites and order all their ISPs to block everything not on the list.

However, apart from North Korea, which seems to have only a single internet provider and only 28 domestic sites (! really?), no country is probably insane enough to do this. The whitelist would need constant updating and soon become unmanagably huge if the country didn't want to suffer the commercial impact of its internet censorship.

If they did it using a blacklist of known VPNs, they'd always miss some of them. Tor for example has a  number of bridges not on any list, and that number changes as people add bridges or decomission old ones, so using a blacklist wouldn't work.

China is a good example of the blacklist approach; they block many sites for their own people, but they can't get 100% success rate; tech-savvy people know how to circumvent the great chinese firewall. Even so, limiting access for the other 98% of the population (I made that number up, I have no clue what the actual percentage is) may be enough to keep unwanted information out of the public consciousness.

Comment: The Great Firewall of China is not able to blacklist all VPN servers so they block the VPN traffic instead.

Comment: With the China example, I was thinking more along the line of blocked websites due to them having unconvenient truths on them (such as the history of Tiananmen square massacre). I think this is done using both keyword blacklists and url/domain blacklists.

Comment: Their firewalls are far more sensitive. It actually detects openVPN traffic and tor. They use **packets fingerprinting**.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the internet by a normal user is done using a provider which connects local networks with the wider internet. This is true also for access to VPN's. If the government is able to order the essential providers in the country to block access to known VPN or to even only allow access to known good sites or even block every kind of internet access then this would effectively mean that none of these VPN is reachable from inside the country anymore.

Since strict blocking can have unwanted side effects like possible overblocking another strategy might be to make access to such VPN simply unlawful and monitor internet access.  With enough control of the government over the providers such monitoring can be established too. In many cases it might be enough that users feel that they are watched and experience that others get punished so that they stop accessing VPN in order to not violate the law.

Thus, technically it is possible to block access to VPN's for most or even all users inside a country or just make most of them "voluntary" abandon VPN usage. If it is possible by law is a legal question which depends on the local laws and is off-topic here.

Comment: While this is technically true of course, if they want to maintain some level of access to the internet, it gets really hard and/or expensive to filter out access to *all* VPNs. Tunneling traffic in all kinds of other traffic will always be an option as long as there is something to tunnel in. :)

Comment: @lengyelg: you are right but the question if the negative side effects are worth the expected positive results is I think off-topic here too. The question was if this is possible and yes it is. And there are countries which are doing this.

Comment: @lengyelg it's impossible to do a very selective blocking that still allows most of benign/normal communications; but it's quite possible to have a "great firewall whitelist" that allows only a very limited set of external connections, specifically chosen to not include anything with encrypted, secure channels to arbitrary destinations. You can do content-sniffing (expensive performance requirements but possible) and seeing anything that looks like an encrypted connection, do an "in-person audit" on the source of these packets. And you can simply disconnect everyone except for your officials.

Comment: Tor obfuscated bridge protocols do a good job of hiding encrypted traffic in a way that won't trigger content sniffing firewall blocks. But of course, its an arms race; whatever the bridge protocol designers come up with can be countered sooner or later by the firewall guys...

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible to ban all VPNs, other things exist to fight internet censorship. Technology like Tor bridges, for example, is aimed at people residing in countries like China where VPN related traffic is discriminated against. A person without direct access to a VPN could, in theory at least, connect up to a Tor bridge and then to a VPN if they so desired.

Another possibility is, for the more tech savvy user, to have a machine or VM which is innocuous or changeable enough that sshing to it won't raise any concerns, and then port forward. Some interesting areas of thought here would be proper configuration of ssh, whether a series of port forwards would be more secure or even practical, whether port forwarding through a VPN would be either practical or helpful, tunneling your HTTP and SMTP traffic over another protocol which is generally perceived as innocuous... there are so many possibilities here.

A lot of papers exist on this topic, as well as products that are an upgrade from, say, sketchy free VPNs (or even cheaper sketchy paid ones). Happy to link to some interesting stuff if wanted.